# Manage Jackrabbit Groups ACL. Access Denied adding node on node with group privileges

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

In jackrabbit repository, i'm trying to add privileges to a GROUP. I want what "designers" group can write into /templates node.

This node (/templates) is a node with type nt:folder

First, i create a group named "designers"

```
userManager = jkSession.getUserManager();

        Roles[] rolesTable = { Roles.EDITOR, Roles.DESIGNER,
                Roles.OPERATOR, Roles.ADMINISTRATOR };

        for (Roles role : rolesTable) {


                userManager.createGroup(role.toString());

            ...
```

and assign privileges to this group for /templates node:

```
    p = principalManager.findPrincipals(
                                Roles.DESIGNER.toString(),
                                PrincipalManager.SEARCH_TYPE_GROUP)
                                .nextPrincipal();
    Node catalogNode = session.getRootNode().getNode("templates");

                AccessControlPolicyIterator accessControlPolicyIterator = accessControlManager
                        .getApplicablePolicies(catalogNode.getPath());

    AccessControlPolicy policy = accessControlPolicyIterator
                                .nextAccessControlPolicy();

                        if (polic

y instanceof AccessControlList) {

                        AccessControlList acl = (AccessControlList) policy;

                        JackrabbitAccessControlList jackAcl = (JackrabbitAccessControlList) acl;
                        jackAcl
                                .addEntry(
                                        p,
                                        new Privilege[] {
                                                accessControlManager
                                                        .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_ADD_CHILD_NODES),
                                                accessControlManager
                                                        .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_READ),
                                                accessControlManager
                                                        .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_WRITE),
                                                accessControlManager
                                                        .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_REMOVE_NODE) },
                                        true, null);
```

Now, create user and makes him members to designers group:

```
    Principal principal = principalManager.findPrincipals(DESIGNER.toString(),
            PrincipalManager.SEARCH_TYPE_GROUP).nextPrincipal();
Group roleToAssign = (Group) userManager.getAuthorizable(principal);

        user = userManager.createUser(login, password);

        roleToAssign.addMember(user);
```

now login with that user and try addNode to /templates

```
lCredentials = new SimpleCredentials(login, new String(pPassword)
                    .toCharArray());
        }

        Repository tmpRepository = null;

        try {
            tmpRepository = repositoryFactory.getRepository(repositoryParams);
            session = tmpRepository.login(lCredentials, pWorkspace);
```

and add node to /templates:

session.getRootNode().getNode("templates").addNode("test","nt:unstructured");

But throw accessDenied:

```
javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: Access denied.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager.checkPermission(DefaultAccessManager.java:193)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1266)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.AddNodeOperation.perform(AddNodeOperation.java:111)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.AddNodeOperation.perform(AddNodeOperation.java:37)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNodeWithUuid(NodeImpl.java:1814)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1774)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getOrAddNode(JcrUtils.java:519)
```

I don't find documentation about ACL on jackrabbits groups. Please ¿can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

For privileges on principals (groups or users) must use **Principal-Based ACL**, not resource ACL like i did in this post.

Principal-Base ACL is described in:

[Jackrabbit ACL](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl) (yes, this post has been a RTFM case)

But **Additionally** is necessary adding privilege **JCR_NODE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT** in privileges list for adding child nodes of a particular type.

```
    privileges = new Privilege[] {
                                    accessControlManager
                                            .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_ADD_CHILD_NODES),
                                    accessControlManager
                                            .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_READ),
                                    accessControlManager
                                            .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_WRITE),
                                    accessControlManager
                                            .privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_NODE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT) };
```

Thanks.

Comment: The key point here is to add JCR_NODE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT. It is NOT necessary to use principal based ACL, resource ACL works just fine. BTW JCR_WRITE already includes JCR_ADD_CHILD_NODES so that does not need to be added explicitly

Comment: I can also confirm you will need all four privileges in order for the "add child" privilege to work. You must have JCR_ADD_CHILD_NODES+JCR_READ+JCR_WRITE+JCR_NODE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT.

In my case I wanted to have ability to allow child node adding *without* having the actual node itself be writable. I guess that's a case the JCR designers didn't anticipate. This is unfortunate, because in the "Social Media" world it a common pattern to have content user(s) can "read" and you want them to be able to comment on it but not EDIT it.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.